Prove $\sum_{(n,m)\in[-N,N]^2}\frac{1}{(z-\pi n)(z-\pi n-\pi m)}\to\frac{1}{2}+\cot^2(z)$
Problem: prove that
$$S=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{(n,m)\in[-N,N]^2}\frac{1}{(z-\pi n)(z-\pi n-\pi m)}=\frac{1}{2}+\cot^2(z) \tag{1}$$  I was trying to generalize $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\frac{1}{z-\pi n}=\cot(z)$ [ref] (*) to n-dimensional sum then I came across the sum $(1)$.
I tried solving it by (*):
$$S=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\frac{1}{z-\pi n}\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{m=-M}^{M}\frac{1}{(z-\pi n)-\pi m}$$
$$=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\frac{1}{z-\pi n}\cot(z-\pi n)=\cot(z)\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\frac{1}{z-\pi n}=\cot^2(z)$$
I just realized this is a silly attempt and it's obviously wrong.
I also thought about partial fraction, change of index, residue theorem but none of them works.
My false answer differs the correct answer by $1/2$, it suggests a known phenomenon of conditional convergent sum, for example:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-2N}^{N}\frac{1}{z-\pi n}=\frac{\ln2}{\pi}+\cot(z) \tag{2}$$
$(2)$ is pretty straightforward given (*), but I can't prove $(1)$ the way I prove $(2)$.
Question: How to prove $(1)$?
(If possible, I hope your solution is generalizable to n-dimensional sum)
